# prestashop 1.6 - change my account address field order

Tags: smarty, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'm trying to change the fields order of the form in the MyAccount > address form (in the front end) in prestashop 1.6.

I updated the **/themes/mytheme/address.tpl** template and moved the country above the city (that's all I want to do), but when I refresh the page it doesn't seem to work.

I tried to delete the cache files inside the /cache directory but it doesn't change anything.

So are you supposed to proceed when you want the country field BEFORE the city field?

Basically, I changed this code:

```
{if $field_name eq 'city'}
        <div class="required form-group">
          <label for="city">{l s='City'} <sup>*</sup></label>
          <input class="is_required validate form-control" data-validate="{$address_validation.$field_name.validate}" type="text" name="city" id="city" value="{if isset($smarty.post.city)}{$smarty.post.city}{else}{if isset($address->city)}{$address->city|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}{/if}{/if}" maxlength="64" required/>
        </div>
        {* if customer hasn't update his layout address, country has to be verified but it's deprecated *}
      {/if}
      {if $field_name eq 'Country:name' || $field_name eq 'country' || $field_name eq 'Country:iso_code'}
        <div class="required form-group form-select">
          <label for="id_country">{l s='Country'} <sup>*</sup></label>
          <select id="id_country" class="form-control" name="id_country" required>{$countries_list}</select>
        </div>
      {/if}
```

And turned it into this code:

```
      {if $field_name eq 'Country:name' || $field_name eq 'country' || $field_name eq 'Country:iso_code'}
        <div class="required form-group form-select">
          <label for="id_country">{l s='Country'} <sup>*</sup></label>
          <select id="id_country" class="form-control" name="id_country" required>{$countries_list}</select>
        </div>
      {/if}
{if $field_name eq 'city'}
        <div class="required form-group">
          <label for="city">{l s='City'} <sup>*</sup></label>
          <input class="is_required validate form-control" data-validate="{$address_validation.$field_name.validate}" type="text" name="city" id="city" value="{if isset($smarty.post.city)}{$smarty.post.city}{else}{if isset($address->city)}{$address->city|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}{/if}{/if}" maxlength="64" required/>
        </div>
        {* if customer hasn't update his layout address, country has to be verified but it's deprecated *}
      {/if}
```

And I cleaned the cache, but when I refresh the page, the template is not updated. 
(I'm sure it's the right template file because if I put some garbage strings in it, they show up).

I also tried with the "Force Compile" option but it doesn't work either.

Comment: enable the option "Force Compile" and refresh your page

Comment: Could you please show the code you modify?

Comment: @JahangirAlam I tried "Force Compile" but it didn't work

Comment: give a try: go to root/cache/smarty and then run the commands :                1. sudo rm -rf cache/*      2. sudo rm -rf compile/* then delete root/cache/class_index.php, refresh your page

Answer (score 0):

Moving around form group blocks will do nothing because they are generated from an address format list so form groups are generated in that order.

Address format for United States is stored in database like this (single string separated by newlines `\n`):

```
...
city, State:name postcode
Country:name
...
```

So city will always be displayed before country name if it's an United States address format.

You can change this without modifications by going to backoffice menu

`Localization -> Countries` choose a country and you can modify address format.

However the order of fields is changed everywhere on site.

If you need a different order of fields only on address form page you will have to either rearrange `$ordered_addr_fields` array in [assignAddressFormat()](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/1.6.1.x/controllers/front/AddressController.php#L326) method or do it in template [address.tpl](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/1.6.1.x/themes/default-bootstrap/address.tpl#L50) before foreach loop begins.

Best way to do it though without tampering base files is to create a module with a [DisplayOverrideTemplate](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/1.6.1.x/classes/controller/FrontController.php#L1461) hook and modify smarty variable there before outputting.

```
$this->context->smarty->tpl_vars['ordered_adr_fields']->value = array(/* Reordered list here */)
```